# Likelihood for mixture of Bernoulli Distributions

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

Given are n independently distributed binary vectors, each of dimension d.
They are distributed according to:

$X_{ij} ∼ ber(1 − θ), λ_{j} = 1$,

$X_{ij} ∼ ber(θ), λ_{j} = 0$,

for 1 ≤ j ≤ d and 1 ≤ i ≤ n where $λ_{j}$ selects the Bernoulli source. The likelihood has then the form:

$p(X|\theta, \lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{d} ber(X_{ij}|1-\theta)^{\lambda_{j}} ber(X_{ij}|\theta)^{(1-\lambda_{ij})}$

My question is, why is there the second product $\prod_{j=1}^{d}$? I would expect in place of it rather sum from j=1 to d. Is it due to the fact the the input vectors are binary and we can thus conveniently express sum as a a product? This has quite a significant role in that when the likelihood is expressed with product instead of sum, it allows for convenient max-logLikelihood solution.